# Navigation bar gradient color

Tags: html, css

How can I color the navigation bar like this?

[image]

Black in the top left corner and blue in the bottom right corner and make a gradient in between them.

Comment: Have you tried to look for css gradient before posting? If so, what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```css
.box{
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 34%, rgba(44,153,221,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(34%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(44,153,221,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 34%, rgba(44,153,221,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 34%, rgba(44,153,221,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 34%, rgba(44,153,221,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 34%, rgba(44,153,221,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#2c99dd', GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to learn how linear-gradients work I would go here: [MDN linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
.link {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, black 30%, DeepSkyBlue 100%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="link"></a>
  <a class="link"></a>
  <a class="link"></a>
  <a class="link"></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for.

```css
.box {
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 18%, rgba(3,152,252,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(18%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(3,152,252,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 18%, rgba(3,152,252,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 18%, rgba(3,152,252,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 18%, rgba(3,152,252,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 18%, rgba(3,152,252,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#0398fc', GradientType=1 );
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```